# Need for countable compactness in this proof for metric space convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

The question I am trying to answer reads as follows.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$ a countably compact subset. We suppose $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $A$ and that the corresponding set $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has an accumulation point $a \in A$. Prove there is some subsequence of $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $a$.

This seemed initially straightforward to me. We can construct the sequence $(y_{n})_{n}$ where $y_{k} \in (B(a, \frac{1}{k}) \setminus \{a\}) \cap (x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, after which showing the convergence of $(y_{n})_{n}$ seems to follow naturally.

I'm pretty sure I must have the wrong idea or completely be missing something here however, since as far as I can tell I didn't have to rely upon the fact that $A$ is countably compact. I know that countably compact means that every infinite subset $Q$ of your considered set $R$ has an accumulation point within $R$, but I'm struggling to see both:

- What is wrong with my proof?
- How I am going to use countable compactness of $A$ to construct a correct proof.

Any hints or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right that countable compactness isn’t needed here, but you have to work a little harder than that in order to make $\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ a subsequence of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$. What you get from your argument is a sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ of positive integers such that $y_k=x_{n_k}$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, but you don’t know that the sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is strictly increasing. To complete the argument you must show that it has a strictly increasing subsequence; that will give you a subsequence of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converging to $a$. It’s not hard to do: the key step is to show that $\{n_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ must be infinite.

The reason that countable compactness isn’t needed is that we assumed that $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ has an accumulation point $a$. If $A$ is countably compact that assumption is unnecessary: either $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is finite, in which case the sequence has a constant subsequence, or $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is infinite and therefore has an accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Brian. One further point - I think I can see how to show that $n_{k}$ must be infinite, by simply considering a ball of radius $\frac{1}{m+1}$ were it finite where $m$ is the last element of the finite sequence. However now I'm trying to find some justification for any infinite sequence of integers having a strictly increasing subsequence... Am I on the right track here?

Comment: @hermitude: You’re very welcome. Yes, you are on the right track. Take your argument a little further, and you can see that each integer can occur only finitely many times. Now it’s not hard recursively to construct a strictly increasing subsequence.

Comment: Hey Brian, sorry to keep you. One further question - while finishing up my version of the proof, it occurred to me that maybe the order of my arguments is a bit silly. Could I not just inductively select increasing elements from $(x_{n})_{n}$ to form $(x_{n_{k}})_{k}$ such that $x_{n_{k}} \in B(a, \frac{1}{k}) \setminus\{a\}$ to get a convergent subsequence in the first place?

Comment: @hermitude: Yes: you just need to explain why $B\left(a,\frac1k\right)\cap\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is infinite, since that’s what ensures that you can pick $n_k$ larger then $n_{k-1}$.